# Application with SmartTable and JSONModel binding

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to develop SAPUI5 application using smart table with the json model binding.
[While running this program I'm getting error I'm sharing that snapshot with you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYZ3S.png)
I'm sharing my code, please suggest me to how to achieve this

In view:

```
<smartTable:SmartTable 
        id="smartTable_ResponsiveTable"
        smartFilterId="smartFilterBar" 
        tableType="ResponsiveTable" 
        editable="false"
        entitySet="tableSet"
        useVariantManagement="false"
        useTablePersonalisation="false" 
        header="Products" 
        showRowCount="true"
        useExportToExcel="false" 
        enableAutoBinding="true"
        initiallyVisibleFields="name">
    </smartTable:SmartTable>
```

In Controller:

```
var array = [{
                "name" : "Dinesh",
                "id" : "123"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Nikhil",
                "id" : "456"
            },{
                "name" : "Pulkit",
                "id" : "789"
            }];
            var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            model.setData({
                tableSet: array
            });
            this.getView().byId("smartTable_ResponsiveTable").setModel(model);
            });
```

Please suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

it's not possible to bind jsonData Model to a smart table. The columns/rows on a smart table are defined based on the metadata.xml of an odata service.

Check this: https://answers.sap.com/questions/90310/application-with-smarttable-and-jsonmodel-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

What do you obtain if you attempt to define the columns in the view?

```
<smartTable:columns>                        
(your columns)                  
</smartTable:columns>
```

Regards,
Gabriel

Comment: Hi Gabriel, Thank you for giving reply. I added columns tag to my code like below <smartTable:columns> 
   
  </smartTable:columns> After adding this i'm getting following error failed to load 'sap/ui/comp/smarttable/columns.js' from https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/comp/smarttable/columns.js: 404 - error. Please say what is the problem and say how to add column inside of it (please provide sample code) Regards, Dinesh

Comment: the example on explored does not define the columns in the xml view, so I have no fast way of knowing if is possible. The only one advice is to try to follow the example in explored:

Comment: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable/samples

Comment: Ok Gabriel, I will try that but I think it is entity set issue because same UI with northwind odata service model is working fine but here i'm trying with json model, with json model it is not showing results. Any idea about how to set json model to smart table